# Как можно ускорить выполнение данного цикла?

Tags: python, циклы, while

[image: 1]Игра "Friday Night Funkin'", нужно что бы программа видела стрелки и в нужный момент нажимала кнопки, но из за проблем со скоростью программы она пропускает некоторые.

```
while True:
    img = screenshot(region=(1025, 142, 630, 200))
    result1 = img.getpixel((60, 77))
    result2 = img.getpixel((233, 69))
    result3 = img.getpixel((391, 50))
    result4 = img.getpixel((565, 80))

    if result1 == (194, 75, 153):
        press('left')
    elif result2 == (0, 255, 255):
        press('down')
    elif result3 == (18, 250, 5):
        press('up')
    elif result4 == (249, 57, 63):
        press('right')
```

Comment: Что значит ускорить?

Comment: Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы программа считывала информацию с экрана и при необходимости нажимала нужную кнопку, но она не справляется со скоростью, и не успевает вовремя нажать на кнопку.

Comment: А если скриншотить маленькими кусками, только нужными для проверки - не будет быстрее? Скриншотить маленький кусочек и тут же его проверять. Если if сработал, то остальное и не проверять.

Comment: Скриншоты и так делаются по минимуму.

Comment: if тоже пробовал, эффекта - 0.

Comment: попробуйте добавить `sleep()` скажем на 200-300 миллисекунд - у вас уходит слишком времени на __непрерывный__ IO

Comment: Только замедлило

Comment: А порядок if-elif важен или случайно расставили?

Comment: порядок не важен

Comment: Ну значит `python` для этой задачи не подходит.

Comment: Ну других языков пока что не изучал(

Comment: Что такое `screenshot`? Это откуда? Измеряли время работы этой функции?

Comment: У вас не правильный подход, к решению этой задачи

Comment: А если делать 4 скриншота размером в пиксель, это не быстрее будет?)

Comment: Идея интересная, стоит попробовать, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что, если вместо одного большого скрина сделать четыре по 1-му пикселю? Измерил:

```
from pyautogui import screenshot
from time import time

count = 10

def a():
    screen_region = (1025, 142, 630, 200)
    
    for _ in range(count):
        screenshot(region=screen_region)

def b():
    a, b, c, d = (
        (60, 77, 61, 77),
        (233, 69, 234, 70),
        (391, 50, 392, 51),
        (565, 80, 566, 81)
    )
    
    for _ in range(count):
        screenshot(region = a); screenshot(region = b)
        screenshot(region = c); screenshot(region = d)

def test(fn):
    start = time()
    fn()
    return time() - start

for _ in range(10):
    print( test(a), test(b) )
```

Вообще, оно довольно таки медленно работает, 4 скрина делаются ровненько в 4 раза медленнее, чем один, вывод получился таким:

```
0.4999725818634033 2.0658695697784424
0.5010006427764893 2.0397465229034424
0.5019679069519043 2.129403829574585
0.5289437770843506 2.0051631927490234
0.5073909759521484 2.1189193725585938
0.4999434947967529 2.0218682289123535
0.5023987293243408 2.0898818969726562
0.5019710063934326 2.088815927505493
0.5014889240264893 2.0067667961120605
0.5019707679748535 2.1762630939483643
```

Т.е. 1 скрин он делает за `0.05` секунды (около 20 в секунду). На такой скорости все остальные микро-оптимизации вряд ли будут играть какую-то роль. Возможно, отказ от синхронного цикла что-то изменит, пробуйте:

```
from pyautogui import screenshot
from threading import Timer

screen_region = (1025, 142, 630, 200)

px_l = ( 60, 77); color_l = (194, 75, 153)
px_d = (233, 69); color_d = (0, 255, 255)
px_u = (391, 50); color_u = (18, 250, 5)
px_r = (565, 80); color_r = (249, 57, 63)

def loop():
    img = screenshot(region = screen_region)

    if img.getpixel(px_l) == color_l:
        press('left')
    elif img.getpixel(px_d) == color_d:
        press('down')
    elif img.getpixel(px_u) == color_u:
        press('up')
    elif img.getpixel(px_r) == color_r:
        press('right')

    Timer(0, loop).start() # функция асинхронно вызывает саму себя, как только сможет

loop()
```

На создание кортежей тоже уходит немного времени? Вынес из цикла. И `img.getpixel()` перенес прямо в условия: Не придется каждый раз получать все 4 значения.

Если всё равно этого не хватает - ищите другой способ получить цвет пикселя на экране (вероятно, с этого и следовало бы начинать, т.к. скриншот фактически нигде не используется)

Comment: Собсна, получение цвета пикселя уже неоднократно обсуждалось на этом сайте

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, пойду пробовать.

Comment: Ну если скриншот настолько тормозной (причём, независимо от размера области), то копать нужно именно в эту сторону - как ускорить скриншот (если это возможно), остальное всё мелочи действительно.

Comment: А какой  принцип игры? Когда стрелочка встанет в паз, надо нажать  соответствующую клавишу?

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: У вас получилось задуманное?

Comment: Попробуйте создать еще на каждый скрин, процесс обработки.(то есть смотреть в сторону multiprocessing)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй заменить конструкцию if-else на switch-case. В пайтоне это делается с помощью словаря.

```
d = {(194, 75, 153):'left', (18, 250, 5):'up', (249, 57, 63): \
'right', (0, 255, 255):'down' }
print(d[(249, 57, 63)])
```

и оставь аргумент к словарю кортежем для скорости.
Я пока не мерил скорость, но стоит попробовать.

Comment: Там у автора `img.getpixel()` берет цвета разных пикселей, всё равно придется 4 раза проверять)